# Wrong data type value

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have been working on a project in windows **Excel**, but now I have to change it to **LibreOffice Calc** and the function returns `#VALUE!`, but works normally in **Excel**.

Here's the function ( *it searches for a value in a certain column and row* )

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$1400; SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($F$3;$B$3:$B$1400))*
(SEARCH($G$3;$D$3:$D$1400))); ROW($D$3:$D$1400)-MIN(ROW($D$3:$D$1400))+1;"");ROW(A21)));"")
```

And here is how my Worksheet aka SpreadSheet in LibreOffice Calc looks like

[image]

I read somewhere that the Quotes shouldn't be in there so I tried to Remove/Replace them and got value from one cell:

-When I **REMOVED** the *Quotes ""*, it returned a **Random** cells value

-When I **REPLACED** the *Quotes ""* with the number **1** it returned the value of the first person, but in the next cell (since it should find every person with a certain name or if left *Blank* it should find *every Person* in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel the `SEARCH` function will match a blank search cell with all the lookup cells.  In Calc, a blank cell as the search criteria will return an error.

To get the "return all if search cell is blank" behavior you'll need to wrap your searches each in an `IF`, returning a number (so the `ISNUMBER` function returns TRUE) in the case of the search cells being blank:

```
IF($F$3<>"";SEARCH($F$3;$B$3:$B$1400);1) * IF($G$3<>"";SEARCH($G$3;$D$3:$D$1400);1)
```

So your full formula will be entered with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` (since this is an array formula) in cell F8 as:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$1400;SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(IF($F$3<>"";SEARCH($F$3;$B$3:$B$1400);1) * IF($G$3<>"";SEARCH($G$3;$D$3:$D$1400);1)); ROW($D$3:$D$1400) - MIN(ROW($D$3:$D$1400))+1;"");ROW(A1)));"")
```

Copy and paste down however many cells you need.  If you want to paste to a large number of cells, you can highlight them all by typing in the name box (to the left of the formula bar) the range, for example `F9:F1405`, and pressing `Enter`.

Note that in **LibreOffice versions older than 4.4.4.6** the `IFERROR` function will not suppress the error (see [bug 95226](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95226)).  It should work as you expect in newer versions.

## Edit

Both the `IFERROR` and `ISERROR` functions pass this particular error through instead of returning TRUE or FALSE (appears to be a bug in current versions of both OpenOffice and LibreOffice - see the "Issues" section of the OpenOffice wiki page https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ISERROR_function#Issues).

A potential workaround is to not pass any text value to the `SMALL` function.  (The formula above will pass an empty text string to the `SMALL` function if no match is found, thus generating an error).  Instead of the `""` we will pass the last row number in the array - for this to work the bottom-most cell in the range, row 1398 in this case, must be a space (or, it could be empty if it was OK to Tools→Options→OpenOffice Calc→View→UNcheck "Display zero values).

We will also make sure not to tell the `SMALL` function to look for a rank that is larger than the size of the range it is provided.  So like this:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$1400;SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(IF($F$3<>"";SEARCH($F$3;$B$3:$B$1400);1) * IF($G$3<>"";SEARCH($G$3;$D$3:$D$1400);1)); ROW($D$3:$D$1400) - MIN(ROW($D$3:$D$1400))+1;1398);MIN(ROW(A1),1398)))
```

Comment: I just have one more question, since those cells that do not have any found values return *#VALUE!* I would like to know, what changed need to be applied to just leave a Blank space. Otherwise the function and explanation were splendid, thank You very much!

Comment: @McBooley I tested in version 4.4.4.3 and saw that the unfound cells returned *#Value!* instead of a blank; I thought from the note in the bug I linked to that this would be fixed in newer versions.  But it sounds like you have a more recent version and are still seeing the *#Value!* being incorrectly pushed through the `IFERROR` function?

Comment: I've got LibreOffice5 and yes I get *#Value!* from **IFERROR** if there is no returned data, otherwise it works nicely of course

Comment: I read the [bug 95226 report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95226) more closely and it appears to have affected both LibreOffice4 and LibreOffice5 versions.  A comment at the end says someone tested with version 5.03 and the bug was fixed.  The header at the top says target: 5.1.0, which is still in pre-development.  Do you have 5.03 or 5.04 (which might be fixed), or an earlier version of 5?

Comment: I have the 5.0.4 version

Comment: @McBooley I've edited my answer to include a potential partial workaround

Comment: I got the **Err.509** from that last function, but the tip with **passing the last cell instead of " "** and **Unchecking Diplay Zero Values** worked for me. Thank you very much for your patience and effort!